# replace nth matched pattern

Tags: jquery, regex, replace

`.match()` hardcoded javascript method allows you to chose between matched patterns as follow : `.match()[number]` that's correct only if you have the `g` modifier in your `regex`
is there any possible way to do the same job for the `.replace()` method ?
like : 
`.replace(/pattern/g,'myText')[number]`
to loop through found or 'matched' results and chose a specific one of them to change ?
or any jquery plugin that exist for this task
for better understanding for my conception here is a jsfiddle [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/ca0Lkg2x/2/)

Comment: You could find the match using `.match()[n]`, then replace that match using it's index in the original string as startindex for the replace method.

Comment: thanks i modified my link

Comment: What is your expected output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible out of the box, you need a function like this:

```
String.prototype.replacen = function(re, replace, n) { 
    var p = 0; 
    return this.replace(re, function($0) { return p++ == n ? replace : $0 }) 
}
```

works like this

```
"abcdef".replacen(/[a-z]/g, "*", 3) // "abc*ef"
```

Comment: here is a [**demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/ca0Lkg2x/6/) for your work thank you for it, even if i honestly didn't understand the code, but i will do my best to analyse it, i don't care if i spend hours doing so, also you could think of making a jquery plugin for this, or even a js plugin and upload it

Comment: It doesn't need to be a jQuery plugin, think of it as a String extension, providing the ability to apply this to any string (whether returned by a jQuery method, a plain JavaScript function or a user-supplied string).

Comment: there is a little bug thou in this, when you try to include a capturing group in your replacement like `$1` it doesn't work at all, here's an [**update**](http://jsfiddle.net/ca0Lkg2x/8/)

Comment: @Amine: yes, this function doesn't work with replacement rules, like `$1` or `$&`. Only literal replacements.

Comment: i found a MDN documentation about this [**here**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace#Specifying_a_function_as_a_parameter)  
`$n` as mentioned regex "flags" (or modifiers in other documentations to avoid confusing) are no longer working, we should use `p1 p2 ...pn` instead, i will work on an update for your function, thanks

Comment: @Amine: `$0` here is just a variable name. I like to name `replace` arguments this way, so that they match `$0`, `$1` in a replacement string, but it's just a choice. You can replace `$0` with `x` or `str` or any other valid identifier.

Comment: please help or provide any documentation about passing a function as parameter for replace method, MDN made me so confused

Comment: @Amine: what exactly didn't you understand? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace#Specifying_a_function_as_a_parameter

Comment: @georg in the MDN, Specifying a function as parameter#2 for replace method  |  
this so called function only accepts the following parameters : `match, p1 p2 ... p9, ofset, string` how come you pass `$0` as argument ? (question1)  |  
in MDN they said : `Note that the function will be invoked multiple times for each full match to be replaced if the regular expression in the first parameter is global`  |  
how could you loop through each match separately ?(Q2)  |  
can your code be replaced with [**this**](http://jsfiddle.net/ca0Lkg2x/9/) ? (Q3)

Comment: @Amine: 1) I choose to call the `match` param `$0`. You can use `match` or `foobar` or whatever else. JS doesn't care how you call your parameters. 2) If you have the `g` flag, and 100 occurrences of the match in the string, the function will be called 100 times. My function doesn't loop - it compares the counter `p` with `n` and returns immediately. 3) No, because, again, each match makes a separate function call. If you loop inside the function, this loop will run for each match.

Comment: @georg i enhanced your code to accept `$1 $2 ...` by simply changing the `replace` parameter by `$0.replace(re, replace)`
here is my enhanced [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/ca0Lkg2x/10/)
please update your answer

Answer (score 0):

One approach to to this is to keep track of the match yourself:

```
$('button').click(function () {
    // first, make sure we have a number (not a string):
    var v = parseInt($('input').val(), 10),
    // create a variable to keep track of 'which' match:
        matchNumber = 0;
    // use the anonymous function available to String.replace():
    result = $('p').text().replace(/12/g, function (a){
        // increment the matchNumber variable (because we're returning in the
        // next line):
        matchNumber++;
        // check to see if matchNumber - 1 (the 'pre-incremented' matchNumber) is
        // equal to the match we want. If it is, we return the specified string ('aa'),
        // otherwise we return the matched string (the variable `a`):
        return (matchNumber - 1) === v ? 'aa' : a;
    })
    $('div').text(result)
})
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/ca0Lkg2x/5/).

References:

- [`String.replace`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace).

Comment: your approach is good and logical, my question was about any pattern in general
the demo was only about 2 numbers
what about if the pattern was for an adress email ? `/.+@.+\..+/` ?
what if it was something else ?

Comment: how come matchNumber keeps track of 'which' match ? you just created a variable then incremented it, how is it related to matches ? and how come `a` is the equal to the variable number, i'v read all the MDN reference and i found nothing